# Populating a dataGridView using DataSets through a Drop-down List

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter, drop-down-menu, dataset

I'm suppose to make two simple DataSets for a small movie database for a school assignment. The assignment also says that I should be able to select an item from a drop down list (populated with one of the DataSets that includes the Movie name) which will filter the results of a dataGridView (populated with the other DataSet) and display the names and roles of the people in that movie.

The real question I have here is that I don't know how to populate the dataGridView with the files from that 2nd DataSet.  I also don't know how to make the SQL filter that changes the data in the dataGridView based on the movie in the drop down, but my main concern is just getting the dataGridView populated at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily filter data by using RowFilter and than you assign that filter data to the datagrid control easily.

For example syntax of Rowfilter:

```
dataset_filter.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter
```

For more details you can check article : [DataView RowFilter Syntax [C#]](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/)

**OR**

you can make use of DataSet to Linq and do something as below

```
DataTable orders = dataSet.Tables["SalesOrderDetail"];

EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query = from order in orders.AsEnumerable()
                                         where order.Field<Int16>("OrderQty") > 2 && order.Field<Int16>("OrderQty") < 6 
                                         select order;

DataView view = query.AsDataView();

bindingSource1.DataSource = view;
```

Comment: So if I already have the query made in the designer for the dataset how would I add or use that?

Comment: You can get the datasource of the grid and than you can perform your operation on that